# How to run archinstall unattended on first boot from Arch Linux ISO

Tags: arch-linux

I would like to modify the Arch Linux ISO (https://archlinux.org/releng/releases/2024.02.01/) so it runs `archinstall` on first boot without user input, passing a config file. The config file will be available on the ISO filesystem.

If possible, I'd like to avoid building a new ISO from scratch using https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/archiso and instead just modify an existing ISO.